# DDD Seller and Buyer entities suggestions

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, bounded-contexts

I'm trying to learn DDD and I want to create a marketplace. I have Seller and Buyer entities in the Sales bounded context. Is this how I'm supposed to write code the DDD way? Will it be better to make Seller and Buyer one entity? And will it be confusing that Buyer has AcceptOffer() method, because Buyer can't accept the offer and the method is used when the Seller Accepts the offer from the buyer to notify the buyer that his offer has been accepted?

```
public class Seller
{
    private readonly ICollection<Product> productsForSelling = new List<Product>();
    private readonly IDictionary<Product, Offer> soldProductsAndOffers = new Dictionary<Product, Offer>();

    private readonly ICollection<Offer> receivedOffers = new List<Offer>();
    private readonly ICollection<Offer> declinedOffers = new List<Offer>();

    public void SellProduct(Product product)
    {
        this.productsForSelling.Add(product);
    }

    public void RemoveProductForSale(Product product)
    {
        this.productsForSelling.Remove(product);
    }

    public void AcceptOffer(Offer offer)
    {
        this.ValidateProductForSaleExistence(offer.Product);

        this.soldProductsAndOffers.Add(offer.Product, offer);
        this.RemoveProductForSale(offer.Product);

        offer.Product.Status = Status.Sold;
    }

    public void ReceiveOffer(Offer offer)
    {
        this.receivedOffers.Add(offer);
    }

    public void DeclineOffer(Offer offer)
    {
        this.ValidateProductForSaleExistence(offer.Product);

        this.declinedOffers.Add(offer);
    }

    private void ValidateProductForSaleExistence(Product product)
    {
        var isProductForSale = this.productsForSelling.Contains(product);
        if (isProductForSale == false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Buyer
{
    private ICollection<Offer> pendingOffers = new List<Offer>();
    private ICollection<Offer> acceptedOffers = new List<Offer>();

    public void CreateOffer(Product product, Seller seller)
    {
        var offer = new Offer(this, product, seller);
        seller.ReceiveOffer(offer);
    }

    public void AcceptOffer(Offer offer)
    {
        if (this.pendingOffers.Contains(offer) == false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        this.pendingOffers.Remove(offer);
        this.acceptedOffers.Add(offer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.
However, Buyer and Seller should be separate entities but you can create a base Entity class for any common code(not the common feature).

There are certain important rules in DDD that can help while designing:

1. The entities should not be anemic(only getter/setter), every public method should have a single responsibility and name should explain that.
   This is also followed in DDD that code should be self explanatory.
2. Also the every entity should have an Id that you can keep in Entity bas class.
3. If an operation spans more than one entity create a DomainService class for that. Like a function involving Buyer and Seller both should be in the service class.
4. If you go for Layered architecture make sure that the domain model should be in package(like a namespace/package in java) and should not refer any upper layers. Make a package diagram for showcasing.
5. Find out all the concepts(Problem space) before start designing(Solution space) like Buyer/Seller/Offer and all the events. It concepts can come up in discussion with domain experts so it will be called as Ubiquitous language.
   You can refer to Event storming technique for this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Seller and Buyer entities in the Sales bounded context. Is this how I'm supposed to write code the DDD way?

I would say yes, because for me `Seller` and 'Buyer' are both concepts of selling. Finally the answer can only give the domain experts. DDD is about listening to domain experts and model bounded contexts as the domain experts think about them.

A bounded context is a context in which a term has a specific meaning. Thus you can have the same term in different contexts, because it has different meanings. E.g. if you are designing an application for a flight company the term *flight* might be used in different contexts. A flight can be the route that a plane will take (origin to destination). A *flight* can also be the thing that a ticket represents for a passenger. Or the company might look at *flights** from the maintenance perspective. In each case the you will have different properties and methods for a *flight* (that change for different reasons -> single responsibility).

> Will it be better to make Seller and Buyer one entity?

No, since a `Seller` and a `Buyer` are individual concepts of the selling domain. In Java I would put them in the same package and make the `Buyer.AcceptOffer` method *package scope* or *protected* so that it is only visible to classes in the same package. You must decide how to do it with the language features of the language you use.

> And will it be confusing that Buyer has AcceptOffer() method, because Buyer can't accept the offer and the method is used when the Seller Accepts the offer from the buyer to notify the buyer that his offer has been accepted?

The domain concept of *accepting an offer* should be placed in one entity, at least the *public* api (see the answer to your second question).

But when you listen to your own definition it gives you another hint:

> the method is used when the Seller Accepts the offer from the buyer to notify the buyer that his offer has been accepted?

The key word is **notify**. The *notify* gives you the hint that there might be a domain event. Thus it is also possible that `Seller` and `Buyer` are the roots of different aggregates and that one aggregate informs the other using domain events.

Diving into domain events and possible implementation solutions goes far beyond  your question. If you are not aware of domain events you should read a book about them first. Either Eric Evans DDD Book or *Implementing domain-driven-design* by Vaughn Vernon.

Comment: Seller sells a product and gets many different offers from buyers but accepts only one.

Comment: @manfrom ahh, I got it. Edited my answer.